# Rails MySQL Active Record Time Zone Not Being Recognized

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, date, activerecord, timezone-offset

I'm having an issue with timezones not pulling through correctly in my searches. When I print out the actual timezone before passing to active record it shows correctly. ex:

```
date = params[:date].split('-') #2022-01-11
@date = DateTime.new(date[0].to_i, date[1].to_i, date[2].to_i)

Rails.logger.info("@date.at_beginning_of_day.in_time_zone: #{@date.at_beginning_of_day.in_time_zone}")
Rails.logger.info("@date.at_end_of_day.in_time_zone: #{@date.at_end_of_day.in_time_zone}")

beginning = @date.at_beginning_of_day.in_time_zone
ending = @date.at_end_of_day.in_time_zone
```

Result:

```
@date.at_beginning_of_day.in_time_zone: 2022-01-10 18:00:00 -0600
@date.at_end_of_day.in_time_zone: 2022-01-11 17:59:59 -0600
```

However when I pass the values to my active record search:

```
@moods = Assessment.select("created_at AS date").where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", beginning, ending).order(:date)
```

It runs the query with the the date NOT in the timezone:

```
 SELECT created_at AS date FROM `assessments` WHERE (created_at BETWEEN '2022-01-11 00:00:00' AND '2022-01-11 23:59:59.999999') ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

My rails app and database are both set to UTC timezone. I can't figure out why the timezone is off on these queries. I have used the `group_by_day` from https://github.com/ankane/groupdate#for-mysql which works fine with pulling in the correct timezones.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by changing

```
@date = DateTime.new(date[0].to_i, date[1].to_i, date[2].to_i)

to

@date = Date.new(date[0].to_i, date[1].to_i, date[2].to_i)
```

and adding `group_by_second(:created_at)` to the `@moods` query. Below is the full updated code:

```
date = params[:date].split('-')
@date = Date.new(date[0].to_i, date[1].to_i, date[2].to_i)

beginning = @date.at_beginning_of_day.in_time_zone
ending = @date.at_end_of_day.in_time_zone

@moods = Assessment.select("created_at AS date").where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", beginning, ending).group_by_second(:created_at).order(:created_at)
```

If anyone knows of a way to do this without needing the group_by_second I'd love to know.